# How to display text on top of containers?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a card game and my UI has a `Column()` with various combinations of children widgets. One child is a `Row`

```dart
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(),
      Container(),
    ],
  ),
```

The `Container()` widgets each display what looks like playing cards. They have `BoxDecorations`to provide a border + a child that's a `Row().` The Row's children display a number (text) and a suit (image).

I would like to flash text over the two playing cards, something that's visible for just a couple seconds, e.g., "Well done." Although I'm always open to help, I assume this will amount to `(Rich)Text()` widgets and some sort of timer or Duration object, and that I can figure it out.

What I'm struggling with is figuring out how to create a text overlay that is both on top of and spans the two images. Do I have to do something like wrap the higher level `Row()` object in a `Stack()`? I hate all that nesting, plus I don't know how to have the text always be on top of everything else.

Comment: Wrap a Row of cards in a Stack, put text after the Row. I don't think there is anything simpler. By "on top of everything else" you mean on top of cards or every UI element?

Comment: a picture or sketch of the card will help you get the right answer

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am going with (pseudocode):

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(),
          Container(),
        ],
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

With the `Row()` centered and the `child:Text()` centered, everything lines up and looks good. I do, however, think I need to spend time and learn about `Positioned()` widgets. I think that will ultimately be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`Overlay`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) widget:

```
 Scaffold(
    body: Container(child: Overlay(initialEntries: [
      OverlayEntry(builder: (_) => Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/random", fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
      OverlayEntry(builder: (_) => Center(child: Text("Overlay", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),))),
    ])),
 ),
```

Comment: @AlC Let me know to delete this, if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: No, definitely keep it. Thank you for responding.